# How do I run multiple sites on the same server using docker and nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to run two sites on django on the same server under different ip, an error occurs that the port is busy, I fixed the ports, but the site does not start. Tell me where is the error please? Ip work, when I go to the second ip I get redirects to the first site. All settings were specified for the second site. At the end, I added the nginx setting of the first site

This is the second docker-compose file and its settings. I would be very grateful for your help

.env

```
#Django
# Should be one of dev, prod
MODE=prod
PORT=8008

#postgres
DB_NAME=xxx
DB_USER=xxx
DB_HOST=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx
DB_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword

#WSGI
WSGI_PORT=8008
WSGI_WORKERS=4
WSGI_LOG_LEVEL=debug

# Celery
CELERY_NUM_WORKERS=2

# Email
EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxxx
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: site_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server.sh
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${WSGI_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
#    environment:
#      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    ports:
      - 81:80
      - 444:443
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name 183.22.332.12;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/site;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/site;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8010;
    }
}
```

default.conf for first site

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name site1 ip_site1;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1/chain.pem;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/artads;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/artads;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8008;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name ip_site2 site2;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/gdr_mr;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/gdr_mr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8013;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.site1 site1;

        location / {
                return 301 https://site1$request_uri;
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by running two sites on Django? do you have to frontends using the same Django backend? if you could explain your situation better it would help. also, please give the error you're experiencing and the compose file that works

Comment: @NoamYizraeli no, have 2 different project

Comment: @Oleksandr it seems that you are running two site at 8013 and 8008, you need to make sure that UWSGI in both applications is not using the port.

Comment: are you running both the django projects in the same docker container?

Comment: @ddfra I have 2 docker compose files, docker network is the same for everyone

Comment: @AhmedAblak  these ports are free, everything starts correctly

Comment: hi @Oleksandr can you please provide the output of `docker ps` and inside each application container can you run `lsof -i :8008 && lsof -i :8013 && lsof -i :80`

Comment: @Oleksandr `docker ps` seems fine. Please confirm if you are receiving any Nginx errors when accessing site2.

Comment: It looks like your containers are running, docker-compose config and nginx config look OK (as long as this accurately reflects your actual files). Are you sure your django app is actually exposed on the correct port? By default, django will use 8000, but you're specifying 8008 in your compose file.

Comment: If someone needs an answer, it is on the Russian version https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329007/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-docker-%d0%b8-nginx-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5/1330265?noredirect=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Roman Tokaren and @Oleksandr

Here the english translated version submitted by @Roman Tokaren [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1330265)

---

You can always argue a lot about the "correct" launch - after all, how many people, so many opinions, but I will describe an example + - of a "convenient" and scalable configuration. For the "convenience" of working in such a configuration, I would suggest installing [nginxproxymanager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) as a reverse proxy and combining containers and [nginxproxymanager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) into one network - after which it will be possible to forward container ports via http (s), tcp, udp to an external interface using the GUI as well as a number of other goodies, such as the generation of SSL certificates and their auto renewal

---

First, let's create the network itself

```
docker network create --driver bridge --subnet 172.26.0.0/24 testnet
```

---

Let's configure NPM ([nginxproxymanager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/)) - by default we will consider the reverse proxy as the last network node, as a result we will get

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.254
    restart: always
    ports:
      # Public HTTP Port:
      - '80:80'
      # Public HTTPS Port:
      - '443:443'
      # Admin Web Port:
      - '81:81'
    environment:
      # These are the settings to access your db
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "172.26.0.253"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "user"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "npm"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx-proxy-manager:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.253
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pwd"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "npm"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pwd"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  testnet:
    external: true
```

---

And configure the container itself

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: ./
    container_name: site_container
    restart: always
    command: ./commands/start_server.sh
    networks:
      testnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.26.0.2
    volumes:
      - ./src:/srv/project/src
      - ./commands:/srv/project/commands
      - static_content:/var/www/site
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
#    environment:
#      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.${MODE}

networks:
  testnet:
    external: true
volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  static_content: {}
```

---

After that, we carry out the initial configuration of NPM according to the [instructions](https://nginxproxymanager.com/guide/#project-goal) and add the host

[image: Domain Setting]

Answer (score 4):

If you want run more than one site in a server, you can

1. use different `ip`
2. use different `port`
3. use different `domain`
4. use different path and rewrite it
   ...

You can choose one of top list tips.

In your config, you choose different ip and same port, but you set all the site to default and not listen the different ip

```
server{
      listen      ip:port;
}
```

Usually IP is just omitted.

Or you can one ip and different port.

```
server{
      listen      port1;
}
```

```
server{
      listen      port2;
}
```

Or you can one ip and one port but different domain.

```
server{
      listen      port;
      server_name 1.a.com;
}
```

```
server{
      listen      port;
      server_name 2.a.com;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running two virtual servers with different IPs on the same machine, you'd want to specify the IP address in the listen directive:

```
server {
    listen      192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      192.168.1.2:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

More on how `nginx` processes requests can be found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html